# how to remove last two "-delimited strings from each line in a large file

Tags: text-processing, sed, text, delete

I have numerous 2GB space-delimited files from a source system.  Each row in each file contains the same number of strings surrounded by " as text qualifiers.

I need to eliminate the last two strings and their text qualifiers from every row in each file. (like removing the last two columns from a columnar report).  With smaller files, I can import into Excel, delimit, delete the columns, save as tab delimited (much more useful than spaces).

Anycase, these files are too large and have too many rows for excel.  So `sed`??

```
"text1" "text2" "text3" "text4" "text5" "text6"
```

Every row has the same number of strings.  How do I drop "text5" "text6" from every row?

Comment: `awk '{$5=$6=""}1' file`...

Comment: @jasonwryan: Or just `awk 'NF=4'`

Comment: @Thor better...

Answer (score 4):

If you know that you always want to delete the last two columns, this idiom can be used:

```
awk 'NF-=2' file
```

I noticed that this does not work with `nawk`, not sure why.  The portable way is to force the field splitting with `$1=$1:

```
awk '{NF-=2} $1=$1' file
```

Output:

```
"text1" "text2" "text3" "text4"
```

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` command will remove the last two space separated, quoted strings from the end of each line from file `infile` and send the results to `outfile`:

```
sed 's/ *"[^"]*" *"[^"]*" *$//' < infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$(NF-1)=$NF=""}1'  inp

perl -pale '$_ = "@F[0..@F-3]"' inp

sed -ne '
   s/" "/"\
"/g
   :a
   s/\n/ /
   /\n.*\n.*\n/ba
   P
' inp
```

### Explanation:

- `awk` code nulls out the last and second-last fields and prints.
- In `perl` fields are stored in `@F` array and the `slice` from 0th to third-last are selected and stored in the current line `$_`. The double quotes  are there to effect the array->string xformation and joined together by the `$"` `superglobal` whose default value is a space. `-p` Perl option then carries the `$_` value to the stdout.
- In `sed` we first turn all the patterns `" "` ---> `"\n"` then we enter a loop where we take back the `\n` till there are two left. At which point of time we use the `P` uppercase p, command to print the first portion of the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

Printing every field till last-2..AWK provided us number of fields in a row using variable NF

```
echo "text1" "text2" "text3" "text4" "text5" "text6" | awk  -v ORS=""  '{
for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i++)print $i, " " ; print "\n"}'
```

Comment: (1) This will put two spaces after each word, including the last one (i.e., at the end of the line).  (2) If you would use `printf` instead of `print`, you wouldn’t need to change ``ORS``. (3) Why bother submitting this when much more elegant awk solutions have already been posted?